# SSMS Call scalar function from linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, microsoft-dynamics

I want to call a scalar function from my linked server [SQLCRM]

```
select 
   o.EstimatedValue [EstimatedSum],
   (select * from OPENQUERY([SQLCRM], 'convert(date, [DBNAME].dbo.fn_UTCToTzSpecificLocalTime(o.tisa_registrationdate, 
                       us.TimeZoneBias,
                       us.TimeZoneDaylightBias,
                       us.TimeZoneDaylightYear,
                       us.TimeZoneDaylightMonth,
                       us.TimeZoneDaylightDay,
                       us.TimeZoneDaylightHour,
                       us.TimeZoneDaylightMinute,
                       us.TimeZoneDaylightSecond,
                       0,
                       us.TimeZoneDaylightDayOfWeek,
                       us.TimeZoneStandardBias,
                       us.TimeZoneStandardYear,
                       us.TimeZoneStandardMonth,
                       us.TimeZoneStandardDay,
                       us.TimeZoneStandardHour,
                       us.TimeZoneStandardMinute,
                       us.TimeZoneStandardSecond,
                       0,
                       us.TimeZoneStandardDayOfWeek),103)')) as DateKey

   from [SQLCRM].[DBNAME].dbo.Opportunity o left join
            [SQLCRM].[DBNAME].dbo.tisa_Article a on o.OpportunityId  = a.tisa_OpportunitySalesId left join
            [SQLCRM].[DBNAME].dbo.SystemUserBase u on u.SystemUserId = 'DB159B57-4A3D-E311-93EC-00155D46BF05' left join
            [SQLCRM].[DBNAME].dbo.UserSettingsBase us on us.SystemUserId = u.SystemUserId
```

After run this query i'm getting the following error:

OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SQLCRM" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".

Which is the correct format to call the function? Thank you

Comment: Already asked on here, try this solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125820/sql-server-how-to-call-a-user-defined-function-udf-on-linked-server

Answer (score 0):

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 
'Server=ipHere\ExtentionNameifHas;Database=DBName;Uid=userName;PWD=Password;'
,'SET FMTONLY OFF;SET NOCOUNT ON;Paste the query over here'
```